# Group documents by timestamp part of the ObjectId in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have Millions of documents in my MongoDB database. The document structure is as follows,

[image]

Now I need to group the data using document creation timestamp which is in ObjectID (_id). I have tried in several way to do this. But the _id is a mixture of timestamp, MachineIdentifier, ProcessIdentifier, and Counter. So it is hard to figure out how to do that. The issue is we can get the timestamp value from _id only after I fetch the data and I couldn't find a way to get that in MongoDB query to a group that. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can use this aggregation stage to get the date as aspect of the `ObjectId`: `{ $project: { dateFromObjId: { $toDate: "$_id" } } }`. Then, group, etc.